# timer in windows phone

Tags: c#, timer, windows-phone-8.1

I have a code like this in windows phone

```
private void btnrun_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    t = 0;
    Start_timer();
}

public void Start_timer()
{
    timer2 = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer2.Tick += timer_Tick2;
    timer2.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000);
    timer2.Start();
}

void timer_Tick2(object sender, object e)
{
    t++;
    txttime.Text = t.ToString();
}
```

At first use, the display right from 1,2,3,4 ... but when you click again, it starts from 2, 4, 6 .... click again, the display 3, 6 ...
Is there a way for it to run your display when clicking the button 1,2,3,4 each failure?
thank!!!

Comment: You need to stop the initial timer before starting a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private void btnrun_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    t = 0;
    Start_timer();
}

public void Start_timer()
{
    if (timer2 != null)
    {
        timer2 -= timer_Tick2; // unassigns the event handler
        timer2.Stop(); // stops the timer
    }
    timer2 = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer2.Tick += timer_Tick2;
    timer2.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000);
    timer2.Start();
}

void timer_Tick2(object sender, object e)
{
    t++;
    txttime.Text = t.ToString();
}
```

EDIT: If you just want to start the timer once, it could be reduced to:

```
private void btnrun_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    t = 0;
    if (timer2 == null)
        Start_timer();
}

public void Start_timer()
{
    timer2 = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer2.Tick += timer_Tick2;
    timer2.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000);
    timer2.Start();
}

void timer_Tick2(object sender, object e)
{
    t++;
    txttime.Text = t.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why not just reuse the existing timer? No need to recreate it every time.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I didn't create the code and I didn't want to change the funcionality. I just provided him a solution that works with what he may want...

Comment: Not exactly since the timer will still be on the old schedule (could be off by up to a second). You want to reset `t` to zero and stop / start the timer every time. Only the initial setup is under an `if != null` check.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT you are right about that, I completely forgot about 't'.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Stop()` method to stop the timer every click before run it again.

```
private void btnrun_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            t = 0;
            timer2.Stop();
            Start_timer();
        }
```

Each timer registers on the same `Tick` callback:

```
timer2.Tick += timer_Tick2;
```

so it's the reason of the problem.

Comment: Doing that on btnrun_Click will cause a NullReferenceException the first time the button is clicked and the timer will never start (at least with the code shown)

Comment: Yes, it's true timer should be initialized.